# Customizing listview to show distinct rectangles

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am aiming to create a listview which looks like a fb newsfeed page as shown:

This is what a fb page looks like:
[image]

What I have right now is this:
[image: my app]

Hence, does anyone know how I could add more than just lines as dividers between each item of listview, so it looks more like distinct rectangles?

---

@nitinmishra I used the image you sent. But this is what it looks like..
[image]

This is the image I used:
[image]

I need it to look more like the screenshot of fb i posted above

Answer (score 0):

@Ankita In facebook those are not rectangles which you're seeing as listview seperator, instead each row of listview has a `card` as background which gives you a look like there is a rectangle seperator in listview, you can use this 9 patch image in attachment to have similar layout as in FB. use this image as background of your custom adapter row[image: 9 patch image]

**SAVE IMAGE WITH THIS NAME** `card_background.9.png`

Comment: Oh i see..hey, I don't see the attachment. How can I access it?

Comment: @Ankita its attached above `card_background.9.png`

Comment: also how do you make the card leave out a margin from the dividers of listview?

Comment: @Ankita since it's a 9 patch it automatically does

Comment: @nitinmishra, please refer to my response above

Comment: @Ankita i'm reattaching the image in zip file copy and paste image witihin rar in your project and remove the previous one http://filepi.com/i/N6Psu8D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44142/discussion-between-nitin-misra-and-ankita)

Comment: @nitinmishra, i added android:background="@drawable/card_background.9.png"> but Ithe resource is not getting recognized and I am getting an error

Comment: @Ankita http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44142/discussion-between-nitin-misra-and-ankita